# How to update table based on the list from an array in php and mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I am developing an application where I need to create challan for customers. But before I ask the question I beg your excuse as I did not search if anyone had already posted similar query. My problem, precisely, is that I am grabbing form data and storing them in an array and finally going to update the same into mysql table with only those tuples guided by the array list. Below is my scheme.

success.php :

```
    <form action="payment.php" method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="100">
    <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="100">
    <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="100">
    <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="100">
    <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="100">
    <input type="submit" />
    </form>
```

payment.php

```
<?php
        if(!empty($_POST['check_list'])) {
            $form_nos = array();

            foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $check) {
                $form_nos[] = $check; 
            }
  // comma-separated list
  $list_form_nos = "";
  for($i = 0; $i<count($form_nos); $i++) {
       if($i == count($form_nos)-1)
         $list_form_nos .= $form_nos[$i];
       else
          $list_form_nos .= $form_nos[$i].",";
  }
  // And finally
  $challan_no = uniqid();
  $challan_date = date("Y/m/d");
  $db->exec("update customers set challan_no=$challan_no, challan_date=$challan_date where cust_id in ($list_form_nos)");
?>
```

My question is that, whether this would work? Though I have not executed the sql part but I would be highly obliged if you provide some elegant other than this.

Comment: To answer your question, yes it would probably work. BUT PLEASE :  escape the user inputs and learn about sql injection. I suggest you look into PDO or mysqli. Also i would filter the POST inputs and use a timestamp instead of a 'date'. Further more, since this looks likes a payment form, i would make sure i'm posting through https and i would use a form token. I'm seeing an implode instead of your for loop.... and so on. Please don't take this badly, but even if this works you still have alot of work to do in my opinion.

Comment: What's a challan?

Comment: Thanks Louis. I have implemented your suggestions.

Comment: Challan is similar to invoice. It is accepted by banks. @ Strawberry